# Determining who is accessing a file on a shared folder in Windows 2008 R2 server / Windows 7

Tags: c#, c++, c, wmi, share

I need to find a way to determine what files on a shared folder are being accessed, and by whom. Commands like "Net Files" and "Net Session" can give this information, as well as PSFile.exe in SysInternals, but I cannot figure out how to do this programmatically. I have found a way to determine who is accessing a share via WMI, but it does not show what file is being accessed. Does anyone know how to do this in C / C++ / C#? Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NetFileEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525378.aspx) level 3 seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772237%28VS.85%29.aspx) (Active Directory Service Interfaces) , some time ago I wrote an article about this topic [`Using Delphi and ADSI to enumerate local and remote shared resources`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/using-delphi-and-adsi-to-enumerate-local-and-remote-shared-resources/) the samples are written in delphi but you can use this article as a guide to ADSI.

To List the opened resources like folders and files you must use the [IADsFileServiceOperations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa706015%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface and the [Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa706016%28VS.85%29.aspx) function which return a collection of the open resources for the service.