# How to check who is using the shared file

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I am on windows 7 Enterprise OS.
I have shared a file to everyone, is there any way to check who all are using this file.

Thanks,

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. Do you want the list of users who currently have the file open or users who have ever opened the file? What kind of sharing are you using? Local file system or remote? Depending on the scenario the answer could be NetEnumFile or Restart Manager or security audits.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, I want to see who(of the machines which connected thru lan) all are using the currently shared file in my local file system.

Comment: Then this is a duplicate of [Determining who is accessing a file on a shared folder in Windows 2008 R2 server / Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854951/determining-who-is-accessing-a-file-on-a-shared-folder-in-windows-2008-r2-server). See also [How to list the open files on a server with a call to the NetFileEnum function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb720835.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can try some third party software like  Manage engine, Netwrix and Lepideauditor for file server  for tracking who is using the shared file.